# Total distance travelled in velocity-time graph

Tags: algebra-precalculus, area

[image: Velocity-time function graph]

I figured out by using trapezium rule. Any other **method** to find out the **total distance travelled** by the car ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the distance travelled is equal to the area under the curve (or more generally, the area between the curve and the time-axis), you have the right idea.

It's very rare that you are given such edgy graphs though, since it is virtually impossible to have travelled in such a manner. The traveler on the graph has obtained speed and come to stops instantaneously, which, as you probably know, can't happen in real life.

**But on to your question...**

Say the graph was smooth. It would be impossible to use rectangles and trapezoids to calculate the area. At best, you could maybe make some estimates, but rarely find an exact answer. When you move on to calculus, you'll be learning about integrals - more specifically **definite integrals** - which we use to calculate the area given smoother graphs.

Comment: Let's say , a is the first hour and b is the second hour. Could I say the **distance travelled (area)** in at the **first hour** can be calculated as :

∫_a^b▒〖y  dx〗

Comment: Evaluating $\int_a^b ydt$ would give you the distance traveled between $t=a$ and $t=b$. It would be the orange area in this little sketch: http://i.imgur.com/dUU1pCz.png

However, evaluating $\int_0^b ydt$ would give you the entire distance traveled from start to finish, with the "finish" being at time $t=b$.

If a = 1 hour, then the distance traveled in the first hour would be $\int_0^a ydt$.